# Animations only play when moving along the Y axis

Tags: c#, animation

My problem is, I have walk animations which only play when my character is moving upward or downward, and I don't know why. This is my code:

```
public float speed = 5f;
private Animator anim;

void Start () {
    anim = gameObject.GetComponent <Animator>();
}

void Update () {
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")));
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")));

    if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") < -0.1f) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1,1,1);
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") > 0.1f) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,1,1);
    }
}

void FixedUpdate {
    Vector3 move = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"),0);
    transform.position += move*speed*Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting

`anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")));`

with

`anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")));`

So only vertical movement is taken into account. To fix it, you can try this

```
anim.SetFloat("Speed",
              Mathf.Max(Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")),             
                        Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"))
              )
);
```